# dotnet build doesn't work with 1 WPF project but all others do

Tags: wpf, build, .net-framework-version, dotnet-cli, .net-4.7.2

I'm having an issue with `dotnet-cli`. and `WPF`, when I right-click the solution and choose build it works every time. No issues, but when I open Developer Powershell and type dotnet build it doesn't compile. It gives me error:

> the name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

I have googled and seen several issues all of which from my understanding does not work with ms build.

Additional Info - .net framework 4.7.2

Why would I get this error with cli and not ms build?